# How do I return early from a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a rake task where I do some checks at the beginning, if one of the checks fails I would like to return early from the rake task, I don't want to execute any of the remaining code.

I thought the solution would be to place a return where I wanted to return from the code but I get the following error

```
unexpected return
```

Answer (score 340, accepted):

A Rake task is basically a block. A block, except lambdas, doesn't support return but you can skip to the next statement using `next` which in a rake task has the same effect of using return in a method.

```
task :foo do
  puts "printed"
  next
  puts "never printed"
end
```

Or you can move the code in a method and use return in the method.

```
task :foo do
  do_something
end

def do_something
  puts "startd"
  return
  puts "end"
end
```

I prefer the second choice.

Comment: I like the second one best, too. The more I use rake, the more I like to keep non-trivial code outside of the task definition. Not a 100% firm rule, but seems to be a good guideline to work to.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Also, methods are much more easier to test.

Comment: The second solution is nicer. In your first solution, I would prefer to use break instead of next to get out of the block... Should work too, shouldn't it?

Comment: @severin Yes, it should. I agree, break makes more sense.

Comment: I've tried with `break` and I've got this error: rake aborted!
break from proc-closure

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: I prefer using next.  Why should we declare a new method just to support early returns?

Comment: I agree, Derek. I'd prefer to keep the code for my rake task within the task definition itself rather than be required to split it into two places (there and a method def). Of course sometimes it makes sense to extract the code into a class or method to make it more testable/reusable, but you shouldn't be forced to.

Comment: Does anyone know why "next" works and "break" doesn't?? "next" sounds like you're in a loop; "break" sounds more appropriate, but I get a "break from proc-closure" if I try that.

Comment: What do you do if you're deeply nested within multiple blocks?  (`next` only works if there's on "level" of block to break out of.

Comment: Warning: declaring methods in Rake tasks is a bad idea because they are global to all loaded Rake tasks, irrelevant of namespace.

Next is used instead of break because the code in the block may be called multiple times by whatever is executing the block (think of the .each method).

Comment: I can't stress enough what @LeslieViljoen said. Declaring the method `do_something` in your rake file means it pollutes _all_ other rake files. There is no "private" methods in rake files. So if you have another rake file that also defined `do_something` you'll get a collision, but worse than that, they will collide silently and you'll find yourself running a completely different method without knowing it. Very dangerous.

Comment: To avoid the nameclash / global namespace pollution, just define your methods as static methods inside a named module.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I've seen this go beyond just affecting other Rake files to actually clobbering methods in a Rails app.  Definitely not a good idea

Comment: I treat rake tasks as a controller. Ideally, a rake task is a single call to a model or service method, with *zero* knowledge of what's under the hood. Sometimes it makes sense to process input and format output in the task, when parameters or output are essential. That code is appropriate in the task (aka controller).

Comment: The answers with the `exit` / `abort` approaches are superior for the reasons noted of correctly setting the exit status. They are also more idiomatic.

Answer (score 212):

You can use `abort(message)` from inside the task to abort that task with a message.

Comment: @TylerRick No, it's [Kernel#abort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-abort).

Comment: This way is superior for exiting in non-success situations as it automatically sets exit status.

Comment: This is a winner. Also an easy way to provide usage feedback for argument errors.

Comment: Inline and much more explanatory than `next`. Love it.

Comment: This might not be a good idea if you are testing your rake task, this will most likely have the test fail.

Comment: I like this in code, but just discovered a problem with it. `abort` goes all the way up the stack. That includes your rspec test. I had `expect(Logger).to receive... call_task()` This did not fail, and in fact did not complete the test. So it *looked* like the test pass, even when I still had a bug in my rake task's `abort` logic. For this reason, I'll go back to `next`. YMMV

Answer (score 47):

### Return with an Error ❌

If you're returning *with* an error (i.e. an exit code of `1`) you'll want to use **`abort`**, which also takes an optional string param that will get outputted on exit:

```
task :check do
  
  # If any of your checks fail, you can exit early like this.
  abort( "One of the checks has failed!" ) if check_failed?

end
```

**On the command line:**

```
$ rake check && echo "All good"
#=> One of the checks has failed!
```

---

### Return with Success ✅

If you're returning *without* an error (i.e. an exit code of `0`) you'll want to use **`exit`**, which *does not* take a string param.

```
task :check do
  
  # If any of your checks fail, you can exit early like this.
  exit if check_failed?
  
end
```

**On the command line:**

```
$ rake check && echo "All good"
#=> All good
```

This is important if you're using this in a cron job or something that needs to do something afterwards based on whether the rake task was successful or not.

---

#### Bonus: Return with an Error from a `rescue` block without the stacktrace.

By default, if you use `abort` inside of a `rescue` block, it will output the entire stack trace, even if you just use `abort` without re-raising the error.

To get around this, you can supply a non-zero exit code to the `exit` command, like:

```rb
task :check do

  begin
    do_the_thing_that_raises_an_exception
  rescue => error
    puts error.message
 
    exit( 1 )
  end

end
```

Comment: This one should be accepted answer @simone-carletti

Comment: No, it shouldn't. This will not just bump you out of the task, it will bump you out of the entire stack, terminating the entire process that invoked it. This will crash your application if you invoke them inline, or give you false positives when you're writing tests for them. Using `next` is the only "right" way of doing it.

Answer (score 23):

I tend to use `abort` which is a better alternative in such situations, for example:

```
task :foo do
  something = false
  abort 'Failed to proceed' unless something
end
```

Comment: But how do you `abort` without exiting with a `1` exit code? Rake tasks are often use in the command line to determine success or failure. Is there a "successful" `abort`?

Comment: Answered my own questions: looks like `exit` is a good way to exit successfully.

Answer (score 13):

If you need to break out of *multiple* block levels, you can use [fail](http://builder.rubyforge.org/files/Rakefile.html).

For example

```
task :something do
  [1,2,3].each do |i|
    ...
    fail "some error" if ...
  end
end
```

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753955/11543.)

Answer (score 9):

If you meant exiting from a rake task without causing the "rake aborted!" message to be printed, then you can use either "abort" or "exit". But "abort", when used in a rescue block, terminates the task as well as prints the whole error (even without using --trace). So "exit" is what I use.

Comment: In general, I think using "exit" instead of return/break is a bad idea since it doesn't just jump out of the *current* proc/method/etc. -- it exits the entire process and skips any code that the caller method may have intended to be run afterwards (including possibly some cleanup). But for a rake task I guess it's probably not a problem...

Comment: _"abort", when used in a rescue block, terminates the task as well as prints the whole error (even without using --trace)._ Boy were you right with this! Couldn't find this anywhere else. I've updated my answer to indicate this as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used `next` approach suggested by Simone Carletti, since when testing rake task, `abort`, which in fact is just a wrapper for `exit`, is not the desired behavior.

Example:

```
task auto_invoice: :environment do
  if Application.feature_disabled?(:auto_invoice)
    $stderr.puts 'Feature is disabled, aborting.'
  next
end
```