# How to explicitly fail a task in ruby rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

Let's say I have a rakefile like this:

```
file 'file1' => some_dependencies do
  sh 'external tool I do not have control over, which sometimes fail to create the file'
  ???
end

task :default => 'file1' do
  puts "everything's OK"
end
```

Now if I put nothing in place of ???, I get the OK message, even if the external tool fails to generate file. What is the proper way to informing rake, that 'file1' task has failed and it should abort (hopefully presenting a meaningful message - like which task did fail) - the only think I can think of now is raising an exception there, but that just doesn't seem right.

P.S The tool always returns 0 as exit code.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the `raise` or `fail` method as you would for any other Ruby script (`fail` is an alias for `raise`). This method takes a string or exception as an argument which is used as the error message displayed at termination of the script. This will also cause the script to return the value 1 to the calling shell. It is documented [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/doc/rake/rakefile_rdoc.html) and other places.

Comment: [`fail`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-fail) is just an alias for [`raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise)

Comment: Right you are. Updated my answer to indicate this.

Comment: @Dan Tenenbaum: Thanks. Replaced with a working link.

Comment: Although similar to `abort`, the latter seems to be more appropriate in this case. `fail` displays a stack trace (not user-friendly output). And raises a `RuntimeError`, which hints that you might want to catch it (since `rescue` defaults to `StandardError` and descendants, to which `RuntimeError` belongs, and to which `SystemExit` doesn't).

Answer (score 29):

You can use `abort("message")` to gracefully fail rake task.

It will print `message` to stdout and exit with code 1.

Exit code 1 is a failure in Unix-like systems.

See [Kernel#abort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-abort) for details.