# Ruby: How do I stop execution and print a string in a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, raise

I am writing a rake task. The thing is that I want to stop execution of the task when `if keeper.has_trevance_info? && candidate.has_trevance_info?` is true. I just want it to print `Another record already has that info!` in the log and stop the task. How would I do that? Would it be `raise` or `throw`?

```
  billing_infos.each do |candidate|
    unless keeper.nil?
      raise "Another record already has that info! Manually compare BillingInfo ##{keeper.id}
             and ##{candidate.id}" if keeper.has_trevance_info? && candidate.has_trevance_info?

    else
      keeper = candidate
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use exception handling to exit the task. You can use 'abort' or 'exit'.

So your code would do something like this:

```
billing_infos.each do |candidate|
  unless keeper.nil?
    if keeper.has_trevance_info? && candidate.has_trevance_info?
      puts "Another record already has that info! Manually compare BillingInfo ##{keeper.id}"
      exit
    end
  else
    keeper = candidate
  end
end
```

Or:

```
billing_infos.each do |candidate|
  unless keeper.nil?
    abort("Another record already has that info! Manually compare BillingInfo ##{keeper.id}") if keeper.has_trevance_info? && candidate.has_trevance_info?
  else
    keeper = candidate
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! exit/abort was the method I was looking for! Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: @Edmund the `abort` lets you specify the message. Outside of that I think they have the same affect. There's a good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316475/how-do-i-return-early-from-a-rake-task