# undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scrape, rake-task

I have a rake task and i'm trying to find the record in the database to be updated. Problem is when i use (params[:name]) it throws out the message undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object. How do i make params available to the rake task? Thanks. I'm new to this and any help is appreciated.

```
task scrape_borisAPI: :environment do

@json = HTTParty.get("http://borisapi.heroku.com/stations.json")

@json.each do |station|

@location = Location.find(params[:name])
    @location.nb_bikes = station["nb_bikes"]
    @location.nb_empty_docks = station["nb_empty_docks"]
    @location.update_attributes(:nb_bikes => "@location.nb_bikes", :nb_empty_docks => "@location.nb_empty_docks")
end
end
```

Originally the rake task looked like this and i'm trying to modify it to update records as opposed to creating new records.

```
task scrape_borisAPI: :environment do

@json = HTTParty.get("http://borisapi.heroku.com/stations.json")

@json.each do |station|
        @location = Location.new
    @location.name = station["name"]
    @location.latitude = station["lat"]
    @location.longitude = station["long"]
    @location.nb_bikes = station["nb_bikes"]
    @location.nb_empty_docks = station["nb_empty_docks"]
    @location.save!
    end
end
```

Comment: You mean you want to be able to pass arguments to a rake task to use them in it? Or, you want to use the `params` from a request in Rails?

Comment: i essentially want the name of each record in the database to be available for the rake task? Does that make sense? thanks

Comment: I understand a bit what you want to do but not how you want to accomplish it. What exactly are you expecting as `params[:name]`. `params` is just a method that is in the context of a request in Rails. You won't find `params` in a Rake task. If what you want is to pass in an argument to a Rake task that's a different thing. Do you understand what a Rake task is?

Comment: I think i do, but now i may doubt myself!I've edited the original question, maybe that helps? I'm trying to find the existing record in the database and then update it.I don't know whether passing an argument in is what i want, i just need the rake to be able to look through the database and if it finds a record with a matching name, update it

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Rake tasks are not Web Requests, only web requests have `params`.
How to do it? Use `ENV`!

```
task scrape_borisAPI: :environment do

unless ENV['name']
  puts "You should set ENV 'name' to something to perform this task!"
  next # Use next, see this Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316475/how-do-i-return-early-from-a-rake-task
end

@json = HTTParty.get("http://borisapi.heroku.com/stations.json")

@json.each do |station|

@location = Location.find(ENV['name'])
    @location.nb_bikes = station["nb_bikes"]
    @location.nb_empty_docks = station["nb_empty_docks"]
    @location.update_attributes(:nb_bikes => "@location.nb_bikes", :nb_empty_docks => "@location.nb_empty_docks")
end
end
```

Then you can run your task in this way:

```
bundle exec rake scrape_borisAPI name=Something
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i just don't know how to do what you suggest.

Comment: What you mean? I wrote the entire code even the bash command, you don't need anything else

Comment: I mean that it doesn't do anything...i was trying to edit it because it wasn't working. Sorry.

Comment: That is your code, you should make it works, I just copy-pasted what you wrote in your question. I only added ENV['name'] thing which **is working**, I have it working in thousands tasks I wrote so is nothing special (it's also very simple code, hard to create a bug). If your API scraping code is not working, you should check it by yourself, but that's not the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be calling rake task from within the code you can write a rake task that takes in arguments.

`namespace :whatever do
  desc "desc of task"
  task :task_name, [:arg1] => :environment do |task, args|
  puts "Your argument is #{arg.arg1}"
  #Do all that you want.
  end
end`

you can write your description of rake task and then call it with that param that you want and you can to the update operations. Calling the task is like : `rake whatever:taskname[argument]`

Comment: Thanks for your help but i just don't know how to do what you suggest.

Comment: @jamesarobbo can you give the piece of code where you call the rake task ?